# Is there a function that incorporates the predict(), table() and then round()

Tags: function

I am using the train function in caret in R programming language to generate predictive models. I have used the below code to generate the models.

```
    # Define the sampling methods and models
    sampling_methods <- c("none", "boot", "LGOCV", "cv", "repeatedcv")
    models <- c("LogitBoost", "gbm", "rf")
    
    # Function to fit the caret model
    WE_Proportion_fit_caret_model <- function(sampling_method, model) {
      # Set the seed for the model
      set.seed(sample(1:100, 1))
      
      # Create the caret model control
      ctrl <- trainControl(method = sampling_method)
      
      # Fit the caret model
      WE_Proportion_fit <- train(Lethal ~ .,
                                 WE_SP_Train_Final, method = model, trControl = ctrl)
      
      # Return the fitted model
      return(WE_Proportion_fit)
    }

# Iterate over sampling methods and models using purrr
WE_Proportion_results <- crossing(sampling_method = sampling_methods, model = models) %>%
  mutate(model_fit = map2(sampling_method, model, WE_Proportion_fit_caret_model))

# Print the results
print(WE_Proportion_results$model_fit)
```

I was wondering if anyone knew of a function that can incorporate the predict(), table() and then round() on the WE_Proportion_fit_caret_model object? Thanks. Instead of typing the below code over and over for each model object, I would prefer to have a function that included the predict(), table() and round() commands, which could be applied to each model object:

WE_boot_RF_pred <- predict(model_boot_RF, WE_Test_Year, type = "raw") WE_boot_RF_tab <- table(Actual = WE_Test_Year$Lethal, Predicted = WE_boot_RF_pred) WE_boot_RF_CEM <- round(compute.eval.metrics(WE_boot_RF_tab) * 100, 2)
WE_boot_RF_CEM

Comment: It would help to know what language this is written in.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorporate"?

Comment: Sorry. It is written in R.

Comment: By incorporate, this is what I mean: Instead of typing the below code over and over for each model object, I would prefer to have a function that included all the below code, which could be applied to each model object. :WE_boot_RF_pred <- predict(model_boot_RF, 
                           WE_Test_Year,
                           type = "raw")

WE_boot_RF_tab <- table(Actual = WE_Test_Year$Lethal, 
                        Predicted = WE_boot_RF_pred)

WE_boot_RF_CEM <- round(compute.eval.metrics(WE_boot_RF_tab) * 100, 2) 
WE_boot_RF_CEM

Comment: Happy to provide any other details anyone needs. Thanks

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it